# Finder - search in specific subfolders across the whole drive

Tags: finder, spotlight, search

I am trying to find a way how to search in specific subfolders through the whole drive on my mac. I will try to explain what I need exactly; 
I have a folder with images called "Photos", which includes subfolders; each of these subfolders has a date as a name and includes at least 2 another subfolders called ORIGINALS and EDITS. Images in "originals" and "edits" folder have matching names. 
When I search using command+F in "Photos" folder, my results are duplicated and I want to be able to include only files from "edits" folder. 
Is this possible to achieve? 
Thanks

Comment: I don’t think this question is a duplicate of the linked question. This question asks for a way to exclude all folders named ORIGINALS nested somewhere within the Photos folder. Customizing a saved search to do so would require listing all such folders.

Check out [HoudahSpot](https://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot/). With HoudahSpot you can search the Photos folder and then filter search results to exclude results where the path contains ORIGINALS.

Note: I am the developer of HoudahSpot.

Comment: Thanks, Pierre, I will try this option as it looks the closest to what am I trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a script that uses the `find` command and the `dirname` command to do this but as for doing it in spotlight somehow I don't think so. If you'd like to see a one-liner to do this on the command line I can do this, but it depends on what you want it to output- the containing directory or the full path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those situations I'd just use [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) - freeware from the App Store.

It's slower than Spotlight, as it doesn't use an index, but its search parameters are far more easily defined & no Terminal-fu required.